# Is an NSManagedObject sets itself to nil after a segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm following a tutorial  how to use Core Data, and now specifically how to Update in core date.

So I have a simple notes app and I want to update core data when a user taps on a cell in the table view (means he wants to edit an existing note, rather clicking the plus button to create new note)

So as they suggest in the tutorial in the notes list prepareForSegeue i create an instance of the creating note view controller and set an NSManagedObject instance and passing the note (i did added a property of NSManagedObject to the creating view controller.h) and passing it the note (as a NSManagedObject).

Like this:

```
NSManagedObject *selectedNote = [self.notes objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        destination.editNote = selectedNote;
```

when I save the data i preform this check:

```
if (self.editNote) {
            [self.editNote setValue:self.myTextView.text forKey:@"content"];
        } else {

        // creating a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newNote setValue:self.myTextView.text forKey:@"content"];
        }
```

Now my question is does after I assign the editedNote to the creation view controller property is it set back to `nil` when I get back to the notes list?

Because if it doesn't every time i perform this check:

```
if (self.editNote)
```

It's not going to be nil...
So how does it knows if its a different note each time?

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense.  But you appear to be asking why there is an `if(self.editNote)` check in the code.  It appears to be there because the self.notes array may not have Note object at the selected row index.  So if the user clicks an empty(?) row, at that point, a note is created.   Your code doesn't show where newNote would be saved in self.notes, however.

Comment: Yes, it would be set to nil because the view controller is deallocated when you go back to the table view controller (most likely anyway, since I don't know which tutorial you're using).

Comment: @rdelmar great thanks! thats what i suspected just wasn't sure :)